# sql length function

Tags: sql, oracle

I got an assignment to show name and the letter length from first name and last name and order it by longest length.

[image]

I tried this SQL command without order but the length is weird .tx

```
select 
  FIRST_NAME || LAST_NAME as NAMA, 
  LENGTH(FIRST_NAME) || LENGTH(LAST_NAME) as PANJANG 
FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE LENGTH(FIRST_NAME) || LENGTH(LAST_NAME) > 10
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QI6m.jpg)

Comment: Please don't SHOUT in your question title or text (SQL is fine in CAPS). There's no reason to SHOUT at us. All CAPS text is more difficult to read and understand, and will not get you answers more quickly. In addition, it's extremely rude to come here and SHOUT FOR ATTENTION when you're asking us  to volunteer our time to help you solve a problem. When you see the questions on the main page, you don't see them in ALL CAPS for a reason; that is not acceptable here. Please stop now. Thankks.

Comment: i`m sorry sir didn`t mean to shout just habit when make subject, thanks for the reminder :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the lenght of the combined first name and last name.

```
select first_name || last_name as nama
      ,length(first_name||last_name) as panjang
  from employees
 where length(first_name||last_name) > 10
```

Your code:

```
length(first_name) || length(last_name)
```

takes the length of the first name, then the length of the last name, and concatenates that result.

Comment: i see, i first tried length(first_name, last_name) no wonder it didn`t work, thank you,

Answer (score 1):

`||` concatenates two strings; and will implicitly cast its operands to strings so it can concatenate them. When you want to add two numbers (lengths) you want to use the `+` operator:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME || LAST_NAME as NAMA, 
       LENGTH(FIRST_NAME) + LENGTH(LAST_NAME) as PANJANG 
FROM   EMPLOYEES
WHERE  LENGTH(FIRST_NAME) + LENGTH(LAST_NAME) > 10
```

Comment: so we can use + to add two number, just learn this, thanks for the knowledge sir ..